# React native on android doesn't show images

Tags: android, react-native

I have one big problem on Android in React Native.

The React version is 0.39

The `render function` is as follows:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
            <View style={{ height: y_vis, width: x_vis}} onStartShouldSetResponder={this.onBullsEyeMove.bind(this)} onMoveShouldSetResponder={this.onBullsEyeMove.bind(this)} onResponderMove={this.onBullsEyeMove.bind(this)} onResponderRelease={this.onBullsEyeSet.bind(this)}>
                 <Image style={{position: 'absolute', top: top * -1, left: left * -1, width: p_width, height: p_height}} source={this.state.item.image} resizeMode="contain"></Image>
            </View>
       </View>
    </View>
)
```

On `iOS` it works fine, like is should, but on android a have a strange problem.

Only first time it renders the photo, second time it renders white screen, without photo.

Is it an react native bug as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8677) or is it something else? Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: can you please check by removing `resizeMode` for Android

Comment: @JigarShah I tried it. But no success.

Comment: Remove `resizeMode` and add key in image like ```key={'image_${Date.now()}'}```

Comment: @NisargThakkar No success. The same problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting your Top and Left to 0 and see if it appears in the top left corner?

Comment: @basudz Yes? But the problem is the same. There is nothing wrong with styles, because it renders fine first time.

Comment: @Boky ah yeah. I haven't ran into this problem, but my image source properties are always a uri or a direct require statement.  I've never just injected a state variable into it.

Comment: [**Let them know**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8677#issuecomment-244036202)

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf I just did it. That is the only thing that I can do.